# New to Ubuntu! Help?

Tags: command-line, sudo

Good Morning Everyone,

I have taken the leap to Linux from a life of Windows and OS X. And I'm stuck!

I am trying to install Sense from the Open University and it looks like I have to follow a manual install for the time being, but their guide assumes I already know how to do this.

See this extract:

As root:

```
unzip /path/to/sense-linux-install-b187.zip -d / chmod a+rx /usr/bin/sense.sh chmod a+rx /usr/bin/scratch_squeak_vm chmod a+rwx /usr/lib/Sense
```

(To become root in Ubuntu, prefix commands with ‘sudo’ to run them as root. To become root on Fedora, first issue the command ‘su’ to change identity to the root user.)
Ubuntu additional steps

Ubuntu 11.04 and later require two more packages to be installed. Give the command:

```
sudo apt-get install libssh2-1 libcurl3
```

Running Sense

You can now run Sense with

```
/usr/bin/sense.sh
```

or just

```
sense.sh
```

You’ll probably want to create a shortcut to this file, for easier access.

I have already downloaded the zip file containing the files, and I managed to work out how to access terminal and entered the first line, which look like it unpacked as I can now search Sense in apps and find the, but it doesn't do anything when I click the icon.

Answer (score 2):

It saying that you should install additional packages, so copy and paste this line to the terminal and press Enter:

```
sudo apt-get install libssh2-1 libcurl3
```

Then icon should work, if it doesn't again open the terminal and type:

```
sense.sh
```